# How to pass multiple elements to containsAll method of the list utility object in thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, arraylist, thymeleaf

As we can find if an element exists in a contained list using the #list utility object in thymeleaf using the following syntax,

```
/*
 * Check if element or elements are contained in list
 */
${#lists.contains(list, element)}
```

which works fine with the below code,

```
${#lists.contains(fruits, 'APPLE')} //works & returns true
```

How can we pass mulitple parameter and check if that exists in the list.? The thymeleaf docs has this syntax,

```
${#lists.containsAll(list, elements)}
```

So I've tried passing comma separated values in the elements part of the expression. But din't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the the curly brackets like `{'ELEMENT1', 'ELEMENT2', ...,'ELEMENT N'}` and it worked fine.

Here's the actual code,

```
${#lists.containsAll(fruits, {'APPLE' , 'ORANGE'} )}
```